# How to design the following dropdown layout?

Tags: listview, layout, drop-down-menu

[image]

Hi everyone!

I am stuck in designing the following layout. There are three buttons. On clicking the Category button and the Sort By button, I need to open a popup containing a listview. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this tutorial you will find all customizations of popup menu and popup window with animation.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/303248-popupmenu-contextmenu-and-custom-popupwindow-all-in-one/